# Problem with Window.event.keyCode and .dat memory read VBS hta

Tags: if-statement, events, vbscript, hta, keycode

Basically, what I am trying to do is to create a system where I can store keycode in a .dat file named Bindings and use them to define the key associated with an action. For example the key <kbd>escape</kbd> is translated into keyCode format into "27" and in hta in the script tag if you create a sub named `document_OnKeyDown` the variable `Window.event.keyCode` is created with the a keyCode associated with it for example if I press <kbd>escape</kbd> the var `Window.event.keyCode` = 27 but when I define the action to close the page to the keyCode in the aforementioned file it suddenly the keyCode 27 of the Bindings file is not equal to the 27 of `Window.event.keyCode` for some reason.

So I tried and this is what happened:

The bindings file

> close 27
> pause 32
> loop 82
> minus 37
> plus 39
> up 38
> down 40

The script in my hta included in the <script> tag

```
' to read in memory
Function Read(Path, Var)
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile(Path, 1) ' 1 = reading, 2 = write, 8 = write at the end

    allData = File.readall
    File.Close
    For Each ln In Split(allData, vbCrLf)
        VarName = Split(ln, " ", 2)(0)
        If VarName = Var Then
            output = Split(ln, " ", 2)(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' memory management (vbs does not have one for objects only vars have one)
    Set File = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

    ' return
    Read = output
End Function

Key_close = Read("C:\Users\[login name]\Desktop\Repos\[my repo]\dat\Bindings.dat", "close")

' Called each time a key is pressed
Sub document_OnKeyDown
    lnum = Window.event.keyCode
    If Window.event.keyCode = Key_close Then msgbox "worked"
    If Window.event.keyCode = 27 Then
        msgbox Window.event.keyCode & vbCrLf & 27 & vbCrLf & "Window.event.keyCode = 27"
        If 27 = Key_close Then 
            msgbox 27 & vbCrLf & Key_close & vbCrLf & "27 = Key_close"
            If Window.event.keyCode = Key_close Then msgbox "Window.event.keyCode = Key_close"
            If lnum = Key_close Then msgbox "lnum = Key_close"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The result was only two msgbox's the first one being

<kbd>27

27

Window.event.keyCode = 27</kbd>

The second one being:

<kbd>27

27

27 = Key_close</kbd>

But nothing else I do not understand

Why is 27=27 true but 27=27 not true like whaaat?

Comment: String subtype vs Integer subtype. Change `Read = output` to `Read = CInt(output)`

Comment: Thank you so much I had a hunch that it was something like this but couldn't understand since I never really knew there were variable types in vbs if you want just create an answer out of this and i'll mark it as the answer for this question

Comment: You're welcome. There's probably a good duplicate already. I'll wait and see on that.